# Clarification about AC and DC coupling on oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope, measurement, zener, voltage-measurement, coupling

I was measuring voltage on zener diode and found unclear behavior of oscilloscope.
So I have function generator which puts saw wave(or sine, doesn't matter) of 20 Vpp. It goes through 1k resistor to 5.1 zener diode. Like on the picture.
[image]
If I probe the diode with DC coupling set on oscilloscope channel - I get expected waveform i.e. voltage cuts on around -0.8 Volt when forward biased and around 5.1 when reverse biased.
But when I use AC coupling on the channel, the waveform looks weird and doesn't maen anything useful at all - now it swings from -2.4 to 3.8 - which is not what you expect from this circuit.
So I get that the waveform we got is not the AC, but rather DC biased AC(though we still have -0.8 volts). But what happens with AC coupled measurement on oscilloscope? Why does it take such a weird shape? Where -2.4V and 3.8V came from?

P.S. Should stop asking silly questions in the middle of the night... AC coupling just dropped the "DC bias" to zero... duh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They come from the RC constant of the high-pass filter created by your circuit and the AC coupling of the scope itself. If you look carefully you'll notice that it still swings the same amount (3.8V-(-2.4V)=5.2V), but the waveform loses definition due to the filter.

Comment: But what portion of negative wave required for signal to be not affected by AC coupling(i.e. be genuine AC signal)? I mean if I would have signal of -2 to +5.1 volts(lets suppose zener with high forward bias) - would it be affected the same way? What about -2.5 to +5.1? -3 to 5.1? Where is the line? I guess it is different for every oscilloscope, but what is usual?

Comment: *Every* signal with a frequency greater than 0Hz is an AC signal around an arbitrary DC bias. AC coupling just causes the scope to completely ignore said bias.

Comment: If you had a sine wave signal that was evenly biased around ground (say it went to +2 volts and -2 volts), it should appear the same whether you use AC or DC coupling.  A low frequency square wave would get distorted - a fast rise (or fall) on the leading edge, then droop towards 0 volts with AC coupling.

Comment: oh, my comment was stupid, should have thought before posting it, I get it now, sorry :) Thank you.